# Вызов метода в иерархии класса

Tags: java

есть интерфейс Animal который имеет метод getSpeed()

есть класс реализующий интерфейс Cat с таким же методом

есть класс наследующий Cat Cheetah переопределяющий метод.

вопрос: если я создам объект Animal a = new Cheetah() и вызову a.getSpeed() то вызовется метод из какого класса?

Comment: создай классы, запусти, посмотри

Answer (score -1):

Вызовется метод у того класса, который вы создали. Т.е. у Cheeatah.
Вопрос академический из азов ООП. Очень жаль, что не потрудились посмотреть сами.